# If $V$ is a vector space and $U$ & $W$ are subspaces of $V$, such that $U \oplus W = V$! Need help with proofs!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces, proof-verification

Consider the map $\rho : V \to V$, defined by $\rho(v) = u − w$, where $v = u + w$, $u \in U$, $w \in W$.

Show that:

i. $\rho$ is well defined and it is linear;

ii. $\rho(u) = u$, $\forall u ∈ U$;

iii. $\rho$ is an isomorphism and $ρ \circ ρ = 1V$ , where $1V$ denotes the identity map on $V$.

I have no idea how to do these, but just guessing these answers:

i. Because $\rho$ maps to itself it is well-defined, and it's linear because it's going from $V \to V$, and thus the dimension is singular and doesn't change?

ii. Because it goes from $V \to$, for all $u \in U$, there is a solution $\rho(u)$ that is in $V$?

iii. $1V$ denotes that it's identity is the <1> vector? It's an isomorphism, because it maps from $V\to V$ which is both the same co-domain and range, so they must be isomorphic because they're the exact same?

Comment: Before you try to proof this, you should read some basic definitions again; it seems you don't know what a linear map is, what domain, co-domain have to do with a function...and you should read up on propertis of $U\oplus W=V$ being the direct sum of $U$ and $W$

Comment: I understand it, graphically, but I can't find any explanations of it in my notes from the lecturer, and Khanacademy & Google weren't much help.

Answer (score 1):

**Part i:**
This question is entirely about using definitions.

First, we need to show that $\rho$ is well defined.  In other words, given a $v \in V$, there can only be **one** answer to $\rho(v)$.  In order to prove that $\rho$ is well defined, you need to use the definition of a *direct sum* (i.e. the $\oplus$ symbol).

Showing that $\rho$ is linear means showing that $\rho$ satisfies the definition of linearity.  The key thing to notice here is that if
$v_1 = u_1 + w_1$ and $v_2 = u_2 + w_2$, then 
$$
\rho(v_1 + \alpha v_2) = (u_1 + \alpha u_2) - (w_1 + \alpha w_2)
$$

**Part ii:**
It's enough to note that $u = u + 0$, and $0 \in W$.

**Part iii:**
In order to show that $\rho$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that its kernel (nullspace) is $\{0\}$.

For the next bit, show that for any $u$ and $w$, we have $\rho(\rho(u+w)) = u + w$.  Why is that enough?

---

**More on well-definedness:**

To prove that $\rho$ is well-defined, I would say the following:

> For any $v$, there exist *unique* vectors $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v = u + w$.  Since there is exactly one choice of vectors $u,w$ corresponding to any $v$, the vector $\rho(v) = u - w$ is also uniquely determined.  So, $\rho$ is well-defined.

Consider, on the other hand, what this situation might look like if we didn't have $U \cap W = \{0\}$.  For example, take $U = \{(x,y,0):x,y \in \Bbb R\}$, and $W = \{(0,y,z):y,z \in \Bbb R\}$.

Take $v = (1,0,1)$. We might want to say that $\rho(1,0,1) = (1,0,-1)$ since we have $u = (1,0,0) \in U$ and $w = (0,0,1) \in W$ with $u + w = v$.

However, we could **also** have taken $u = (1,1,0)$ and $w = (0,-1,1)$.  Because of this, we have the second answer $\rho(v) = u - w = (1,2,-1)$, which is clearly not the same as our first answer of $(1,0,-1)$.  So in this case, $\rho$ would **not** be well defined.

Comment: Nice answer, but I assume that it won't help the OP as much, as it seems to me that she is lacking some basic knowledge about (elementary) linear algebra.

Comment: @Hirshy it's hard to say what she knows or doesn't know; she could just be bad at explaining her thoughts. At the very least, this gives her something else to ask about.

Comment: @Gabi Please let me know if there's anything in my answer that you'd like clarified.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, are you saying that for part i. it has to be bijective? I'm assuming alpha is any constant in R? part ii. and iii. make sense now thank you! I think I'm making it more complicated for myself than it is!

Comment: @Hirshy, I can understand algebra for the most part, but I just find it difficult to put it down on paper, whereas I could sketch what's happening between the two no bother!

Comment: @Gabi that is **not** what I'm saying for part i.  Yes, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: @Gabi I think you're thinking of the definition of *injective*, which says that there can only be one $v$ for each $\rho(v)$.  What I'm saying goes back to the definition of a *function*, that is, there can only be one $\rho(v)$ for each $v$.

Comment: Of course it might be that one just can't explain his/her thoughts, but I know these "explanations" for a function being linear or well-defined and they  almost always show, that the person has no idea what he/she is talking about. But then again, there's not much you can do about on this plattform; personal help with some Q&A would be better. And @Gabi, I always hope I'm mistaken, and from other posts I'd say that Omno... will give/lead you to a satisfying answer. :)

Comment: @Gabi Before you answer part i, it's important that you understand (on some level) why the $\oplus$ sign here is important.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DICzG7Xypbo) This is what I used to understand it. What you're saying is that V & W are disjoint subspaces, thus no intersection, and V is both of them combined?

Comment: @Gabi That right.  An important consequence is that for every $v \in V$, there is **exactly one** way to write $v = u + w$ with $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ (in fact, this is sometimes given as the *definition* of a direct sum).  Why does this consequence help us show that $\rho$ is well-defined?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Because p has only one solution for every u in U, and w in W, u + w in V. Therefore, there is no overlap?

Comment: @Gabi I don't understand what you mean here, so it's hard for me to know if you have the right idea. I'll add something to my answer.

Comment: @Gabi see my latest edit.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom p is well defined because for any one combination of u + w, you get only one corresponding v, and therefore, only one p(v), so it's well-defined because there's no ambiguity in it like in the example?

Comment: @Gabi you have it backwards: for any $v$, you get only one combination $u+v$. That's the important thing here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh right, i see now! Thanks a million for the help!